# simple pthread prog with cygwin (unexpected results)

Tags: c, multithreading

I write c program for test pthread (using cygwin) I was expecting the result to be

thread 1
thread 1
thread 2
thread 2
thread 1
....

or any thing near that show me that both thread work in parallel 
but result was
thread 1
thread 1
thread 1
thread 1
thread 1
thread 2
thread 2
thread 2
thread 2
thread 2
T1=0 , T2=0

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
void *funa();
void *funb();

int main()
{
  //create thread
  pthread_t thread1, thread2;
  int T1=pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, funa, NULL);
  int T2=pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, funb, NULL);

  //join thread
  pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
  pthread_join( thread2, NULL); 

  //return 0 if sucess
  printf("T1=%d , T2=%d",T1,T2);
exit(0);
}
void *funa()

{int i;
for (i=0;i<5;i++)
printf("thread 1\n");

}
void *funb()

{int j;
for (j=0;j<5;j++)
printf("thread 2\n");

}
```

Comment: why were you expecting that?  You should never expect any order unless you enforce it with locks of some sort.  Hell, thread 1 is probably done before thread 2 even starts..

Comment: I agree with @xaxxon, you shouldn't really be expecting any behavior with the ordering of the prints. It's possible you'll see thread 2 five times and then thread 1 five times. You have no guarantee. The only thing you know is that you'll see five thread 1 statements and five thread 2 statements

Comment: thanks xaxxon MadDogMcNamara

Answer (score 0):

Stepping back from the question specifics which are already addressed by the other comments, looks like you want some kind of ordering in your threads.

If so, you may want to consider adding some `pthread_barrier_wait()` ([details](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_barrier_wait)) within your for loops. Every call to a barrier will block until all expected threads call the barrier. You should set the number of threads to wait when you initialize the barrier in `pthread_barrier_init()`.